# JTAppleCalendar Swift For Loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, calendar, jtcalendar

I am using the following function to try and print out a Month for each header as you scroll through the calendar. There must be a problem with how I'm doing my for loop as the only month Im getting out is December. Any ideas? Thanks

With the print("(names)"), i am getting all of the months printed out on the console. However, I can't get them printed out correctly visually.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplaySectionHeader header: JTAppleHeaderView, range: (start: Date, end: Date), identifier: String) {

        //let months: [String] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        let months = Calendar.current.monthSymbols
        let headerCell = (header as? MonthsHeader)
        for names in months {
            print("\(names)")
        headerCell?.monthsHeader.text = names

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're overwriting the same `headerCell?.monthsHeader.text` variable with every iteration, so only the last assignment will persist.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, so how could I fix that? Thanks @Alexander Momchliov

Comment: Have you taken a look at the example project attached on github?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do it.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplaySectionHeader header: JTAppleHeaderView, range: (start: Date, end: Date), identifier: String) {
   let startDate = range.start
   let month = myCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: startDate).month!
   let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols[(month-1) % 12]
   let year = testCalendar.component(.year, from: startDate)
   let headerCell = header as? MyHeaderView
   headerCell?.title.text = monthName + " " + String(year)
}
```

myCalendar --> this is a `Calendar()` instance

MyHeaderView-> this is the header class

Comment: What do you mean by calendar instance?

Comment: `myCalendar` is the JTAppleCalendar view.  When I say instance, I mean an initialized object.